# Purge IBM MQ Queue programmatically

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Is there any way to purge IBM MQ Queue programmatically? I have few messages lying in the Queue but when I read the messages using Consumer code , the messages are still present in the queue. I am assuming there are some uncommitted messages present in queue.  I do not have access to MQ explorer so I want to clear the queue programmatically. (either through JMS code or IBM MQ implementation way)

Currently my consumer has jar file **com.ibm.mq-6.0.2.1.jar**  So I prefer to use WMQ classes rather than JMS.

Comment: What does your code look like?  Edit and add it to the question.  It is not helpful if you try to put it in a comment.

Comment: I understand I am using old version of client jar. Let's assume I migrate to new jar which is all-client jar.  Now how do I acheive it programatically.   Also the current jar version I am using does not have feature to purge queue programatically?

Comment: You can get messages off the queue or you can use the PCF interface.  Understanding what you are doing will enable someone to figure out what you are doing incorrect.

Comment: I am trying to purge MQ  queue programatically. Forget what client version jar I am using. Lets say I use all client latest jar.. now How to purge the queue programatically. ?

Comment: I provided 2 options.  You stated "but when I read the messages using Consumer code , the messages are still present in the queue."  Can you show this code so someone can help to fix it.   This is not a give me the codes forum,  you need to show what work you put into it.  See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on stack overflow help for more information.

Comment: I am not supposed to show the code here as I am not the owner. And yes I do research and put effort before posting here.  My question was and is simple. Is it possible to programatically purge a MQ queue? If YES ,  how do we do it in any way.  I don't think so my code is no where related to it.   Thanks

Comment: If you cannot show your code, at least give us a clue about what it does. @JoshMc gave two possible ways you could do it. You tell us your code doesn't work correctly, but we don't know what your code does in order to advise further. Perhaps at least showing some pseudo-code that describes what your application does is a way to get around the perceived code publishing issue?

Comment: you can commit and the retrieve all your messages. not sure which API you are using, but with JMS, do Session.commit() and then MessageConsumer.receiveNoWait()

Comment: What if there are some uncommitted messages by another application. The messages are lying the queue and the receiveNoWait is not able to clear them.

Comment: You would have to have the other application commit the messages or kill the other applications connection to the queue manger to force them to be backed out to the queue.   You can not get or clear (PCF) messages that another application has not committed.

Comment: The other application is already killed. The instance is no more running but still the messages are lying in the queue.

Comment: What does this command show `DIS QSTATUS(QUEUE.NAME.WITH.UNCOMMITTED.MESSAGES) UNCOM`.  The value returned for `UNCOM` will be either `NO` if no messages are uncommitted, or a number if there are messages that are uncommitted, the number is the number of messages that are uncommitted.  If a application that had the messages uncommitted is killed off normally the unit of works should roll back.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully functioning Java/MQ program called 'EmptyQ.java' that will delete all messages on a queue until the queue is empty.  Note: It is one of the sample MQ/Java programs that I posted [here](https://capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html).

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

/**
 * Program Name: 
 *  EmptyQ
 *
 * Description: 
 * This java class will connect to a remote queue manager with the
 * MQ setting stored in a HashTable, loop to retrieve (delete) all messages from
 * a queue then close and disconnect.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters: 
 * bindings mode: 
 *  -m MQA1 -q TEST.Q1 
 *  
 * client mode:
 *  -m MQA1 -q TEST.Q1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class EmptyQ
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat LOGGER_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

   private Hashtable<String, String> params;
   private Hashtable<String, Object> mqht;

   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public EmptyQ()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
      mqht = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * 
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-m") && params.containsKey("-q");

      if (params.containsKey("-c"))
      {
         b = b && params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p");
      }

      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            if (params.containsKey("-p"))
               Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ HashTable.
    * 
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      int port = 1414;
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         if (params.containsKey("-c"))
         {
            try
            {
               port = Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
               port = 1414;
            }

            mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, params.get("-c"));
            mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, params.get("-h"));
            mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(port));
            if (params.containsKey("-u"))
               mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, params.get("-u"));
            if (params.containsKey("-x"))
               mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, params.get("-x"));
         }

         // I don't want to see MQ exceptions at the console.
         MQException.log = null;
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Connect, open queue, loop and get all messages then close queue and
    * disconnect.
    *
    */
   private void receive()
   {
      String qMgrName = (String) params.get("-m");
      String inputQName = (String) params.get("-q");
      MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
      MQQueue queue = null;
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
      gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQGMO_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_MSG;
      MQMessage receiveMsg = null;
      int msgCount = 0;
      boolean getMore = true;

      try
      {
         if (params.containsKey("-c"))
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
         else
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName);
         EmptyQ.logger("successfully connected to " + qMgrName);

         queue = qMgr.accessQueue(inputQName, openOptions);
         EmptyQ.logger("successfully opened " + inputQName);

         while (getMore)
         {
            receiveMsg = new MQMessage();

            try
            {
               // get the message on the queue - request only 1 byte - make it go as fast as possible.
               queue.get(receiveMsg, gmo, 1);
               msgCount++;
            }
            catch (MQException e)
            {
               if ( (e.completionCode == CMQC.MQCC_FAILED) && 
                    (e.reasonCode == CMQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) )
               {
                  // All messages read.
                  getMore = false;
                  break;
               }
               else if ( (e.completionCode == CMQC.MQCC_WARNING) && 
                         (e.reasonCode == CMQC.MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_ACCEPTED) )
               {
                  msgCount++;
               }
               else
               {
                  EmptyQ.logger("MQException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                  EmptyQ.logger("CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
                  getMore = false;
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      catch (MQException e)
      {
         EmptyQ.logger("CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
      }
      finally
      {
         EmptyQ.logger("deleted " + msgCount + " messages");

         try
         {
            if (queue != null)
            {
               queue.close();
               EmptyQ.logger("closed: " + inputQName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            EmptyQ.logger("CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
         try
         {
            if (qMgr != null)
            {
               qMgr.disconnect();
               EmptyQ.logger("disconnected from " + qMgrName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            EmptyQ.logger("CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple logger method
    * 
    * @param data
    */
   public static void logger(String data)
   {
      String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

      // Remove the package info.
      if ((className != null) && (className.lastIndexOf('.') != -1))
         className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

      System.out.println(LOGGER_TIMESTAMP.format(new Date()) + " " + className + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName() + ": " + data);
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * 
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      EmptyQ write = new EmptyQ();

      try
      {
         write.init(args);
         write.receive();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Usage: java EmptyQ -m QueueManagerName -q QueueName [-h host -p port -c channel] [-u UserID] [-x Password]");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: do you have the latest version of MQRead.java and MQWrite.java, which i can see in that website is also written by you, it will be great help for reference with latest API methods. Please share it if you have written new version of the above classes

Comment: @rinilnath The MQ/Java API methods have not changed.  In MQ v7 (I think), IBM change where the constants are located.  Just change "MQC." to "CMQC." in MQRead and MQWrite and then it should compile.

Comment: Thanks CMQC removes the deprecation warning . But there is one more deprecation  from MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE. can you please suggest the alternative

Comment: I strongly suggest you start doing internet searches and also reading the MQ KnowLedge Center.  What is the first link you get using Google for `MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE`?  It is a link to a page in the MQ KnowLedge Center (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQException.html) that says MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE is depreciated and what to use.  i.e. **_Deprecated. use MQConstants.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE instead._**  Or you can use CMQC class.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this in my project recently.

USING WMQ

browse the queue , consume the messages destructively from the queue.

Use *CMQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR* in MQMessageoptions to remove message destructively from the queue.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=java-mqc

```
MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
getOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR + CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT
                                + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQGMO_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_MSG;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like this ?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class MQClear {

  private static final String qManager = "QM1";
  private static final String qName = "Q1";

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

      MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
      int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
      MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);

      // not great: while (queue.getCurrentDepth()>0) {
      boolean hasMore = true;
      while (hasMore) {

        try {
          MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
          queue.get(mqMsg);
        }
        catch (MQException ex) {
          hasMore = false;
          if( ex.reasonCode!=2033 ) throw ex; // if this was something other than NO_MSG_AVAILABLE, rethrow
        }
      }

      queue.close();
      qMgr.disconnect(); 
    }
    catch (MQException ex) {

      System.out.println("A WebSphere MQ Error occured : Completion Code " + ex.completionCode
          + " Reason Code " + ex.reasonCode);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never ever get messages from a queue based on the "Current Depth".  The current depth includes non-committed messages.  Also, the current depth value is a snap-shot of the depth of the queue at a particular moment in time.  It is far, far better to loop and get messages until the an exception of reason code of 2033 (MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) is thrown.

Comment: yes, I was think about this approach first (getting message until there's no more), but unfortunately the MQ API method get() is a bit cumbersome in that it throws an expection instead of returning null (or an error code) if there's no more message. JMS is nicer in that respect.  Either way, I've change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @himanshu Khullar, in my case I had to send two commands to the queue manager. First, I had to move to the first position and then proceed with the deletion.

Piece of my code:

```
MQQueueManager qManager = null;
MQQueue       objQueue = null;
Queue queue = null;

int           depth;

logger.info("Opening a channel to QL " + this.queue.getName());

objQueue = this.qManager.accessQueue(this.queue.getName(), MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_BROWSE);
depth = objQueue.getCurrentDepth();

logger.info("Messages in queue [" + depth + "]");

MQGetMessageOptions optionMsg = new MQGetMessageOptions();
MQMessage objMsg = new MQMessage();

//-- Read queue and delete each message
while (Boolean.TRUE) {

    //-- Move the cursor to right position
    optionMsg.options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
    optionMsg.matchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;
    optionMsg.waitInterval = 5000;

    objMsg = new MQMessage();
    objQueue.get(objMsg, optionMsg);

    // Delete message
    optionMsg = new MQGetMessageOptions();
    optionMsg.options = CMQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR;
    optionMsg.matchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;
    optionMsg.waitInterval = 5000;

    //-- Get message
    objMsg = new MQMessage();
    objQueue.get(objMsg, optionMsg);
    
}
```